# Prove or disprove that if $f(t) = \frac{1}{e^{-nt}+n-1}$ and $x_1+\cdots+x_n=0$ then $\sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i)\leq 1$.

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, convex-analysis

This question is inspired by [Prove that $\frac{1}{x^3+2}+\frac{1}{y^3+2}+\frac{1}{z^3+2}\leq 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4797820/443030). Let $n \geq 3$ and
$$
f(t)=\frac{1}{e^{-nt} +n-1}
$$
then is it true that for $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n \in\mathbb{R}, \sum_{i=1}^n x_i=0$ we have that
$
\sum_{i=1} f(x_i)\leq 1
$?

The $n=3$ case is proven in the linked question indirectly. For the $n>3$ case I attempted to use Jensen's inequality. However, the problem is that $f$ is concave only on the interval $[-\log(n-1)/n, \infty)$, by checking the second derivative.
Thus, if $x_1 \leq x_2\leq \cdots \leq x_k < -\log(n-1)/n \leq x_{k+1} \leq\cdots\leq x_n$
then by Jensen:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i)=\sum_{i=1}^kf(x_i) + \sum_{i=k+1}^nf(x_i) \leq \sum_{i=1}^kf(x_i) +  (n-k)f\left(\frac{1}{n-k}\sum_{i=k+1}^nx_i\right)
$$
If $k=0$, then the inequality is immediate because $nf(0)=1$. Otherwise, let $P = \sum_{i=1}^k x_i$, $S = \sum_{i=k+1}^n x_i = -P$ and $c = \log(n-1)/n$.
I was thinking to replace the sequence $(x_i)$ by $(y_i)$ where $y_i = -c$ for $1\leq i \leq k$ and $y_i = x_i + \frac{kx_ic}{S} + x_iP/S=kcx_i/S$ for $k< i \leq n$. Then $\sum_{i=1}^n y_i = 0$, and for $k < i \leq n$
$$
x_i \geq -kc/k \geq P/k = -S/k \implies y_i = kcx_i/S \geq -c.
$$
Also $f$ is increasing so
$$
\sum_{i=1}^k f(x_i) \leq \sum_{i=1}^k f(y_i),
$$
so if we can prove that
$$
\sum_{i=k+1}^n f(x_i) \leq \sum_{i=k+1}^n f(y_i)
$$
then the inequality is true by Jensen, however I'm not sure how to prove if this is true.

Comment: I think you can use the method of Michael Rozenberg in the link provided.

Comment: @NN2 Can you provide some more details? In his approach he applies CS, but that seems to work only for the $n=3$ case.

Comment: You are right. In fact, I tried to apply the Cauchy Schwart inequality as he had done but I didn't succeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $y_i = \mathrm{e}^{-n x_i}, \forall i$.
We have $y_i > 0, \forall i$ with $y_1 y_2 \cdots y_n = 1$. We need to prove that
$$\frac{1}{y_1 + n - 1} + \frac{1}{y_2 + n - 1} + \cdots + \frac{1}{y_n + n - 1} \le 1.$$

This is an old problem. See the information in my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3968019/given-positive-numbers-x-1-x-n-such-that-x-1-cdots-x-n-1-prove-that-fr).

Comment: Wow, it's much easier than I thought! Thanks!

Comment: @V.S.e.H. Yes, I believe there are more proofs than the link.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is my proof correct?

Comment: @V.S.e.H. It looks fine. Can we use Karamata's inequality for $x_i$'s on half interval where function is convex?

Comment: Like this $(x_1,\ldots,x_k)\prec (c,c,\ldots,c, x_1+\cdots+ x_k - (k-1)c) \implies \sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i) \leq (k-1)f(c) + f(x_1+\ldots+x_k-kc)$, where $c=-\log(n-1)/n$? Yeah, that works!

Comment: @V.S.e.H. Yes. For half convex half concave function, we do similar things.

Comment: Actually, it's not useful, because it does not allow inserting a free parameter that can go to $-\infty$.

Comment: @V.S.e.H. We may split into cases. First, if $\min x_i > m$, we deal with the problem. Second, the other cases.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**:

For completeness, included the proof that $f$ is concave on $[-\log(n-1)/n, \infty)$. Indeed, we have
$$
f''(t) = \frac{n^2 e^{n t} (1 - (n - 1) e^{n t})}{\left((n - 1) e^{n t} + 1\right)^3} \leq 0,
$$
because $\left((n - 1) e^{n t} + 1\right)^3 > 0$, $n^2e^{nt} > 0$ and $1-(n-1)e^{nt} \leq 1- (n-1)e^{-\log(n-1)} = 1 - \frac{n-1}{n-1} = 0$ for $t\geq -\log(n-1)/n.$

**Proof of inequality**:

Assume wlog that
$$
x_1\leq \cdots \leq x_k < -\log(n-1)/n = c \leq x_{k+1}\leq \cdots\leq x_n,
$$
for some $k\geq 1$. If no such $k$ exists, then the inequality is proven by Jensen.

Otherwise pick $1 < j \leq k$ and define the function
$$
g(t)=f(x_1-t)+f(x_j+t).
$$
Its derivative is
$$
g'(t) = \frac{{ne^{n(x_j+t)}}}{((n-1)e^{n(x_j+t)}+1)^2} - \frac{{ne^{n(x_1-t)}}}{((n-1)e^{n(x_1-t)}+1)^2} = \frac{n ((n - 1)^2 e^{n (x_1 + x_j)} - 1) (e^{n (x_1 - t)} - e^{n (x_j + t)})}{((n-1)e^{n(x_j+t)}+1)^2((n-1)e^{n(x_1-t)}+1)^2}.
$$
Because $x_1+x_j< -2\log(n-1)/n$ we have
$$
(n-1)^2e^{n(x_1+x_j)}-1 < (n-1)^2e^{-2\log(n-1)}-1=0.
$$
Also $e^{n (x_1 - t)} - e^{n (x_j + t)}$ is clearly decreasing (the positive term is decreasing and the negative term is also decreasing), while $e^{nx_1}-e^{nx_j}\leq 0$ because $x_1 \leq x_j$, which proves that $g'(t) \geq 0$ and so $g$ is increasing for all $t\geq 0$.

Now let $y_j = x_j+t \geq -\log(n-1)/n$ for $t>0$ sufficiently large, $y_1= x_1-t$ and $y_i = x_i$ for $i\neq j$ and $i\neq 1$. Then we have using the result from above that
$$
\sum_{j=1}^n f(x_j)\leq\sum_{j=1}^n f(y_j). \label{ineq:0}\tag{1}
$$
We also have wlog that
$$
y_1\leq \cdots\leq y_{k-1} < -\log(n-1)/n \leq y_k \leq \cdots \leq y_n,
$$
and $\sum_{j=1}^n y_j = 0$.

We can repeat this process in a similar way $k-2$ more times, until we are left with numbers $z_1,\ldots,z_n$ which satisfy
$$
z_1 < -\log(n-1)/n \leq z_j,~~ 2\leq j \leq n,
$$
and having sum $0$. By repeated application of $\eqref{ineq:0}$ $k-2$ times and applying Jensen's inequality after, we get
$$
\sum_{j=1}^n f(x_j)\leq\sum_{j=1}^n f(z_j) \leq f(z_1) + (n-1)f\left(\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{j=2}^n z_j\right)= f(z_1) + (n-1)f\left(-\frac{z_1}{n-1}\right)
$$
Taking the limit $z_1\to-\infty$ then the RHS goes to $1$, thus proving the inequality.